# Azure Data Factory Data Flow performance is poor when processing individual files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data flow with a very simple Data Flow that is taking way longer that I am expecting. The flow grabs JSON files from an Azure Blob store, adds a few new columns, then stores it in a Cosmos DB (See image below)

[image: Azure Data Flow]

The JSON files are very small, ranging in size from 1-15kb, and I currently have ~200k files in the blob container.

When I tried to execute this Data flow in a pipeline all by its self, I let it run for over 8 hours before canceling the activity.  I then migrated the data to a Premium Storage Account and re-ran the activity, thinking maybe the SA was the bottleneck.  It has been running now for almost 2 hours and I haven't seen any inserts into the Cosmos DB.  The Monitor screen shows the following:

[image: Data Flow monitor]

[image: Data Flow activity]

Is there some kind of configuration that might be causing this task to take so long?

I tried removing all but 10 files from the container and the process to almost 7 minutes to complete.  Is that normal?  Should I expect the process to take 140000 minutes?

Comment: Is your Integration Runtime re-created each time the pipeline is run? If yes, could it be the start-up time takes most of the duration? 

Also, there are options such as Compute Type, Number of cores to configure for the Integration Runtime to improve performance to consider better performance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#increasing-compute-size-in-azure-integration-runtime

Comment: My IR has a TTL of 10 mins, so I don't believe that it is being re-created or restarted between tasks.  I believe that it is the fact that I have a large number of small files that is the problem.  If I combine all the files into a single large one, it processes significantly faster.